# What is the best way to build a multi-languages website with React

Tags: multilingual, react-i18next, react-intl

I want to build a multi-languages website using react and nodejs, so, I'm asking about the best external module to use and the way to implement it.

Comparing @lingui/core vs. i18n vs. i18next vs. react-i18next vs. react-intl

Answer (score 1):

Since You are building a Reactjs App, there are quite a few i18n packages to choose from.
Personally, I recommend [Lingui](https://lingui.dev/), because of its simplicity.

It uses a macro called `<Trans>Translate this...</Trans>` for code translation and then expand it at compile time.

One good reason why I like them is that they don't force you to provide the `id` of each text you want to translate. You can just use the macro and be able to keep your code as natural as possible and not have to remember all the `ids` of each translatable word.

[Here](https://lingui.dev/tutorials/setup-cra) is their documentation on how to install it

```
yarn add --dev @lingui/cli @lingui/macro
yarn add @lingui/react
```

Then you create a config file `lingui.config.json`

```
/** @type {import('@lingui/conf').LinguiConfig} */
module.exports = {
   locales: ["en", "cs", "fr"],
   sourceLocale: "en",
   catalogs: [{
      path: "src/locales/{locale}/messages",
      include: ["src"]
   }],
   format: "po"
}
```

You can then add your scripts to the `package.json`

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "extract": "lingui extract",
      "compile": "lingui compile"
   }
}
```

Then you can be able to use the Macro for translatable texts

```
import { Trans } from "@lingui/macro"

function render() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1><Trans>LinguiJS example</Trans></h1>
      <p><Trans>Hello <a href="/profile">{name}</a>.</Trans></p>
    </>
  );
}
```

You can see more in their documentation [here](https://lingui.dev/tutorials/react-patterns).